# Why codeigniter 4 gives error "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm learning Codeigniter 4 and i'm using migration to create table. Here is my migration code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class CreateDivisionTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([

            'id' => [

                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 7,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],

            'name' => [

                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '128'

            ],

            'entity_id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'contraint' => '7'
            ]


        ]);
        $this->forge->addPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->forge->addForeignKey('entity_id', 'entities', 'id');
        $this->forge->createTable('divisions');
        //
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('divisions');
    }
}
```

But this give me error like :

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint

at SYSTEMPATH/Database/BaseConnection.php:646

Backtrace:
  1    SYSTEMPATH/Database/Forge.php:546
       CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->query('CREATE TABLE `divisions` (
        `id` INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT `pk_divisions` PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
        CONSTRAINT `divisions_entity_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `entities`(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci')
```

My entities table have id with a primary key. How i can solve this issue ?, If i commented out the addForeignKey() its working for me. But i need the foreignkey to be set.

Comment: Does the `entities` table already exist when the query is executed?

Comment: Yes its fixed. it was the data type problem

Answer (score 0):

try reversing the order first run the migration for entities and then the migration for division as you need an existing relationship field